# Filter HTML Table using multiple select dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a html table that needed to be filtered out depends on selected value on dropdown.

Example Dropdown Category: Name, Age, Gender.

So When selected Age is 18, all  with that value should show, then if gender was selected, only 18 years old Male for example will show etc.

Regards

Comment: Greetings!  I believe you need to include more detail and some code if you want useful feedback from the community.  As it stands, there is insufficient information for anybody to give you any real guidance; in fact, there is no question stated in the post, so it is not clear what you are seeking.  I'd recommend revisiting [ask] for some guidance on crafting questions.  Good luck!

Comment: you can use [datatables](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/examples/options/columnFiltering) to filter html tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using datatables: https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/examples/options/columnFiltering ..